# I have this task to turn a date (which is the value of "birth_date" inside of a dictionary) to a tuple

Tags: python

```
my_dict = {
    "first_name": "Michael",
    "last_name": "Mike",
    "birthdate": "29.06.1980",  # ***
    "hobbies": ["Sing", "Compose", "Act"]
}
```

`"birthdate"` is the key and the date is the value. I need to cast the date to a tuple inside the dictionary so it will be like this:

```
"birth_date": (29,06,1980)
```

Comment: Note you can't actually have `06` in a tuple unless it's a string; that was an _octal literal_ in Python 2.x (but even then you'd see the decimal form when you printed it out) and has been a syntax error since Python 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value corresponding to the `'birthdate'` key, then `split` that string on `'.'`, then convert each value to `int` within a generator expression

```
>>> tuple(int(i) for i in my_dict['birthdate'].split('.'))
(29, 6, 1980)
```

If you want to replace the value in the dict then you can assign this value back to that original key.

```
>>> my_dict['birthdate'] = tuple(int(i) for i in my_dict['birthdate'].split('.'))
>>> my_dict
{'first_name': 'Michael', 'last_name': 'Mike', 'birthdate': (29, 6, 1980), 'hobbies': ['Sing', 'Compose', 'Act']}
```